# simple quiz with jquery and keep tracking the correct answers

Tags: jquery

this is my second attempt in creating a question.

I want to create a quiz with jquery. Each question has two answers, one correct and one wrong. when a question is an aswered then i do not want to be able to be answered again. that is why i make the answers dissappear. they could just as well be unclickable.

Nevertheless, what i really need is to be able to track the score of the correct answers.

And I want the block "Total Results" to appear when all questions are answered.

Anyone has any suggestions?

data-type="1" means the answer is correct

data-type="0" means the answer is wrong

Any improvement of the code is welcome or suggestion for improvements.

I have created the following code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
    .hide{
        display:none;       
    }
 </style>    

<div id="Question1">Question 1
    <div id="answers_q1">
        <div id="answer1_q1" class="ans" data-type="1">answer 1</div>
        <div id="answer2_q1" class="ans" data-type="0">answer 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
    <br />
<div id="Question2">Question 2
    <div id="answers_q2">
        <div id="answer1_q2" class="ans" data-type="1">answer 1</div>
        <div id="answer2_q2" class="ans" data-type="0">answer 2</div>   
    </div>
</div>
    <br />
<div id="Question3">Question 3
    <div id="answers_q3">
        <div id="answer1_q3" class="ans" data-type="1">answer 1</div>
        <div id="answer2_q3" class="ans" data-type="0">answer 2</div>   
    </div>
</div>
    <br />
<div id="total">Total Results
    <div id="answers_total">
        You have <span id="count"></span> correct answers out of total 3 Questions!!!
    </div>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(".ans").click(function(e){

           var res = $(this).attr('data-type');                
           var clickCounter = $('#count').data('clickCounter');
           clickCounter = (clickCounter + res);
           $('#count').data('clickCounter', clickCounter);
           $('#count').html( clickCounter );

        });

        $("#answer1_q1").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q1").html('Correct');
        });
        $("#answer2_q1").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q1").html('Wrong');
        });

        $("#answer1_q2").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q2").html('Correct');
        });
        $("#answer2_q2").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q2").html('Wrong');
        });

        $("#answer1_q3").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q3").html('Correct');
        });
        $("#answer2_q3").click(function() {
            $("#answers_q3").html('Wrong');
        });
        /**/

    });         
</script>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that javascript can be read by the end user (right click on page -> show source)

Comment: yes i know. it does not matter. it is just a simple quiz for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to something like this (to make it a bit more dynamic):

```
<div class="question">Question 1
    <div class="answers">
        <p>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" data-type="0">
            answer 1
        </p>
         <p>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" data-type="1">
            answer 2
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

$(function(){

     $('.answers input[type="radio"]').click(function(){

          var type = $(this).data('type'),
              correctAnswerCount = 
                 $('.answers input[type="radio"]:checked[data-type="1"]').length;

          alert(type === 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong');
     });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7FzPR/2/

Keep in mind that you can simply inspect the html in order to find out the correct answers.

Comment: ok, with that. but i would like it to track the correct answers and when all questions are answered then the total score would appear at the end.

Comment: @sTef http://jsfiddle.net/7FzPR/3/ I added 3 list with dom elements depending on the answers. You can fetch whatever you like from them, or simply display the count. Like `unanswered.length` for example.

Comment: i will check it and get back. one more thing. how would you make it so that the visitor cannot change his answer? (unless of course refresh the page)

Comment: sorry for asking but i cant seem to get it working as I wanted it. Could you please tell me how I can display the count only when the visitor has answered all the questions?

Comment: @sTef Try `if(unanswered.length === 0)`